# Can I pass a default value to a reference for a std::string ?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, default-arguments

```
void doStuff( std::string const & s1, std::string const & s2="");
```

I was wondering if this code is legal in C++, for the s2 string.
I want to have a default argument, but passing a reference and having an empty string as default. Will a temporary be created, and the reference will point to that temporary, or is it illegal C++?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes this is legal. `const` will ensure temporary be lasting till function `doStuff` finishes.

§ 12.2.5

> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.

Answer (score 4):

Better will be

```
void doStuff( std::string const & s1, std::string const & s2 = std::string());
```

To avoid extra temporary `const char *`. (Your variant has 2 temporaries: a `const char *` and empty `std::string`).

Or, using user-defined literals (C++14):

```
void doStuff( std::string const & s1, std::string const & s2 = ""s);
```

Comment: Just for reference: One could also use `std::string const & s2 = {}` as short c++11-compatible version

Answer (score 2):

That to understand the semantic it is better to split the original statemenet .

```
void doStuff( std::string const & s1, std::string const & s2="");
```

into two statements

```
void doStuff( std::string const & s1, std::string const & s2);
doStuff( SomeString, "" );
```

In the call of the function the second argument is implicitly converted to an object of type std::string:

```
s2 = std::string( "" );
```

So in fact in the body of the function you will have

std::string const &s2 = std::string( "" );

That is constant reference s2 will refer temporary object std::string( "" ).